# chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) - NEVER Called

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

Here is my code snippets. I have tried all way but **chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) function is NEVER called.**

**1. BarChart Properties**

```
    self.barChartView.delegate = self
    self.barChartView.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.barChartView.dragEnabled = true
    self.barChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.barChartView.setScaleEnabled(true)
    self.barChartView.highlighter = nil
    self.barChartView.highlightFullBarEnabled = true
    self.barChartView.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.highlightPerDragEnabled = false
    
    //No Data - Place Holder
    self.barChartView.noDataText = "Records Not Found".localized
    self.barChartView.noDataTextColor = .black
    
    //Legend - Bottom Chart Description
    self.barChartView.legend.enabled = false
    self.barChartView.legend.textColor = .black
    
    //Description
    self.barChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    self.barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
    self.barChartView.chartDescription?.textColor = .black
    
    //X-Axis
    self.barChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    self.barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    self.barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    self.barChartView.xAxis.axisLineWidth = 3
    self.barChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = .black
    self.barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = .black
    self.barChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = false
    //X Axis Grid
    self.barChartView.xAxis.gridColor = .black
    self.barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    self.barChartView.xAxis.gridLineDashLengths = [10, 5]
    
    //Y-Axis
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = .black
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.axisLineWidth = 3
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.granularity = 1
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.granularityEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.axisLineColor = .black
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = true
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 1
    //Left Axis Grid
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.gridColor = .black
    self.barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    
    //Right Axis
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = true
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.axisLineWidth = 1.0
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.axisLineColor = .black
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.gridColor = .clear
```

**2. Bar Chart DataSource**

```
 //Y Axis Value
        var yValueAry = Array<Int>()
        var xStrAry = Array<String>()
        //General Event Value for Graph
        var eventValue = 0
        
        //Custom Legend
        var firstLegendText = ""
        var secondLegendText = ""
        
//----------- Bar Chart
        var valueBarChartDataEntry : [ChartDataEntry] = []
        var zeroBarChartDataEntry : [ChartDataEntry] = []
        
        for i in 0 ..< yValueAry.count {
            let yVal : Int = yValueAry[i]
            let barData = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(yVal))
            if yVal >= 1 {
                valueBarChartDataEntry.append(barData)
            }else{
                zeroBarChartDataEntry.append(barData)
            }
        }//FOR END
        
        //Value Bar Chart Data Set
        let valueChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries:  valueBarChartDataEntry, label: "")
        valueChartDataSet.colors = [RDDataEngineClass.clr_eastern_blue]
        valueChartDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = false
        valueChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
        //Value Formatter
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        numberFormatter.positivePrefix = ""
        numberFormatter.positiveSuffix = ""
        let valuesNumberFormatter = ChartValueFormatter(numberFormatter: numberFormatter)
        valueChartDataSet.valueFormatter = valuesNumberFormatter
        valueChartDataSet.valueTextColor = RDDataEngineClass.clr_vivid_violet
        valueChartDataSet.valueFont = UIFont(name: RDDataEngineClass.robotoFontRegular, size: RDGlobalFunction.dynamicFontSize(14))!
        
        //Zero - QuestionBar Chart Data Set
        let zeroChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries:  zeroBarChartDataEntry, label: "")
        zeroChartDataSet.colors = [RDDataEngineClass.clr_eastern_blue]
        zeroChartDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = false
        zeroChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
        //Value Formatter
        zeroChartDataSet.valueFormatter = valuesNumberFormatter
        zeroChartDataSet.valueTextColor = RDDataEngineClass.clr_vivid_violet
        zeroChartDataSet.valueFont = UIFont(name: RDDataEngineClass.robotoFontBold, size: RDGlobalFunction.dynamicFontSize(20))!
        
        
        //Add Data on Graph
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [valueChartDataSet,zeroChartDataSet])
        chartData.setDrawValues(true)
        self.barChartView.data = chartData
        self.barChartView.legend.enabled = true
        
        //X-Axis Value
        self.barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: xStrAry)
        self.barChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -45
        self.barChartView.xAxis.xOffset = 2
        self.barChartView.xAxis.spaceMin = 0.1
        self.barChartView.xAxis.spaceMax = 0.2
        
        self.barChartView.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.15
        self.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 1
        
        self.barChartView.extraBottomOffset = 10
        self.barChartView.extraLeftOffset = 5
        self.barChartView.extraRightOffset = 0
    
        self.barChartView.resetZoom()
        self.barChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
        self.barChartView.fitBars = true
        self.barChartView.fitScreen()
        self.barChartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
        self.barChartView.data?.highlightEnabled = false
        
        //Scrollling
        self.barChartView.scaleXEnabled = false//true
        self.barChartView.scaleYEnabled = false
        self.barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(8)
        self.barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5, yAxisDuration: 1.5)
```

**3. Value Formatter for Weight Graph**
class ChartValueFormatter: NSObject, IValueFormatter {

```
fileprivate var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter?

convenience init(numberFormatter: NumberFormatter) {
    self.init()
    self.numberFormatter = numberFormatter
}

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
    guard let numberFormatter = numberFormatter
        else {
            return ""
    }
    if value >= 1{
        return numberFormatter.string(for: value) ?? "0"
    }else{
        return numberFormatter.string(for: "?") ?? "?"
    }
}
```

}

**4. Bar Chart delegate**

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    print("Bar selected")
    print("Point: \(entry.x) Value: \(entry.y)")
}

func chartValueNothingSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase) {
    print("Nothing Selected chartView:\(chartView)")
}

func chartTranslated(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, dX: CGFloat, dY: CGFloat) {
}

// Callbacks when the chart is scaled / zoomed via pinch zoom gesture.
func chartScaled(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, scaleX: CGFloat, scaleY: CGFloat) {
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this thread ? https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2383

Comment: @RajaKishan, yes man I have already did it.